# How to constraint a child property when reading a parent list

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following database schema:

```
{
    "events": {
        "$eventId": {
            "eventTitle": "Go shopping",
            "participants": {
                "0": {
                    "id": "0",
                    "name": "John Smith"
                },
                "1": {
                    "id": "1",
                    "name": "Jason Black"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's an array of events, where each event has a list of participants. How to make a **database rule**, where:

- everyone can get event or list of events,
- when getting an event, a full list of participants can only by visible by admin,
- when getting an event, if a user is a participant of the event, the list of participants would retrieve only him, noone else,
- when getting an event, if a user is **not** a participant, the participant list would be empty

Here is my try in rule scheme:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "events": {
            ".read": true,
            "$eventKey": {
                "eventTitle": {
                    ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 100"
                },
                "participants": {
                    ".read": "root.child('users/'+auth.uid+'/role').val() === 'ADMIN'",
                    ".validate": "newData.hasChildren()",
                    "$participantKey": {
                        ".read": "($participantKey === auth.uid || root.child('users/'+auth.uid+'/role').val() === 'ADMIN')",
                        "id": {
                            ".validate": "newData.val() === $participantKey"
                        },
                        "name": {
                            ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 100"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It **does not** work, because when I read events list it doesn't respect `.read` constraint in `participants` and `$participantKey` fields. It just retrieves full list of participants all the time.

@**edit**

In other words. I have this simplified rules:

```
{
    "events": {
        ".read": true,
        "$eventKey": {
            "participants": {
                ".read": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I query for: `events/{eventKey}/participants` I still get an object with participants even though the `participants` read flag is set to `false`.

But, when I **remove** `.read` flag from `events`, then retrieving data respects `.read` flag in `participants`.

@**edit2**

From [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/):

> A .read rule which grants permission to read a location will also allow reading of any descendants of that location, even if the descendants have their own .read rules which fail.

My question is now, how to omit this rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Firebase permissions cascade](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#read_and_write_rules_cascade) downwards. Once you've given a user a permission on a certain level in the JSON tree, you cannot revoke that permission on a lower level in the tree.

That means that these rules will not work:

```
{
  "events": {
    ".read": true,
    "$eventKey": {
        "participants": {
            ".read": false
        }
    }
  }
}
```

The `".read": false` is ignored by Firebase.

Instead you will have to structure your data in a way that allows your security requirements. This is done by completely separating the types of data that have different security requirements.

```
{
  "events": {
    ".read": true,
    "$eventKey": {
        "participants": {
            ".read": false
        }
    }
  }
  "eventparticipants": {
    ".read": false
    "$eventKey": {
        /* This is where you store the participants */
    }
  }
}
```

So you have two top-level lists: `events` and `eventparticipants`. The lists use the same keys for the objects under them: the event id. But since these are two top-level lists, one can be publicly readable while the other is more restricted.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase documentation recommends against using arrays when adding data to the database. The main problem in your code is that you use an array, which is an anti-pattern when it comes to Firebase.

One of the many reasons Firebase recommends against using arrays is that it makes the security rules impossible to write and this is your case.

Because Firebase is a NoSQL database and becase it is structured as pairs of key and valeu, the solution is to use a `Map` and **not** an array. Change the way in which you add data in your database and your problem will be solved.

Comment: When I use `set` on the object, instead of `push` on list it still list everything

Comment: Ok but you still cannot write security rules, which is what you are looking for, correct?